# Iron Router waitOn Does Not Work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

Due to nature of Meteor where the `Template.<name>.rendered` executed before the collection could be retrieved, I have resorted to Iron-Router `waitOn`.

This is to wait a playlist to be enabled before rendering the page. It works in Firefox and IE (ironically) but never in Chrome.

The error pointed out by the Chrome console is `Cannot read property 'uploadType' of undefined` which makes sense since the object/collection failed to load in Chrome.

What should I do to encounter this? FYI the waitOn is like this:

`//router.js`

```
this.route('videoPlayer',{
    path:'/video',
    waitOn: function(){
        return [Meteor.subscribe('videoPlaylist'), Meteor.subscribe('video')];
    }
});
```

It doesnt work even during single subscription.

Comment: Have you activated the default `loading` hook using `Router.onBeforeAction("loading");` ?

Comment: @saimeunt nope. Where should I add it? As far as I understand, waitOn is the one used to hold the rendering.

Comment: You can put it in your global router configuration. I think the problem may arise from Chrome JS engine being faster than Firefox/IE thus triggering a first problematic evaluation of your code in the state where collection data is still unavailable. waitOn should return the subscriptions you want to wait on but it needs the default loading hook which is responsible for the delayed rendering until data is ready.

Comment: I did but still stay the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow this is weird. It works (again, remember in Chrome it wasn't working, the rest of FF and IE is fine. what a funny world ) when I added this to the route.

```
action : function () {
     if (this.ready()) {
         this.render();
     }
 }
```

So this makes me wonder isnt `waitOn` supposed to be enough to do the job?

Comment: Really ? This worked for me ? For me not ... I still have the action method in my route ...

Comment: I have both the waitOn and action in the route, then it works in Chrome. Also I have that `route.onBeforeAction("loading");` after the map declaration. Strange is the world.

Comment: This is very strange! I also use waitOn and the action (Take a liik here: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/845) and it doesnt work! Sometimes I rly hate meteor ...

Comment: @TimoRütten try add 'router.onBeforeAction("loading")`. might be because of that.

Comment: @TimoRütten Did you add it after or before router.map?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61628/discussion-between-timo-rutten-and-haikal-nashuha).

Answer (score 0):

it's not a bug but an intended behaviour, iron router expects you to implement "loading" of some sort, add this line after you define the Router and the waitOn will work as you expect it.

```
Router.onBeforeAction("loading");
```

Comment: This does not help in my case ... I have the same problem and use Router.onBeforeAction('loading'). (And yes, there is a loading template defined)

Comment: you don't really need to define a loading template when you're using the code above, it's instead of a loading template, try removing the loading template (or just rename it) and see if it works.

Comment: @ErezHochman it doesnt work in Chrome even after adding `onBeforeAction`. Why the behavior is different than IE and Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this helps you ... I have the same problem, but the problems do just appear when I reload exactly the page where I need the data object before the rendering of the template.

When I am on another page and just going to the page by clicking a link (in your case a link like this: `<a href="{{pathFor 'videoPlayer'}}">Videos</a>`) everything works fine. But when I am on (in your case) `/video` and reloading the page the error you described appears in my case ... very strang and depressing ...

Comment: that would be ugly. my concern here is why the behavior isnt the same across the browsers. IE and firefox works as intended but not Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem before and I found this video from the developer of iron-router [EventedMind](https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/using-wait-waiton-and-ready-in-routes)

---

For a TL;DW

```js
Router.onBeforeAction(function(pause) {
  if (!this.ready()) {
    this.render('Loading');
    pause();
  }
});


Router.map(function() {
  return this.route('home', {
    path: '/',
    waitOn: function() {
      return Meteor.subscribe('roomList');
    },
    action: function() {
      this.render('home');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Exact;u what I did (see my own answer above). The point is, in the docs it says waitOn is to wait the collection to be ready before rendering and it does in Firefox and IE but somehow in Chrome it requires all 3 mechanism to work (waitOn, action, onBeforeAction) I am sure something wrong with Chrome.

Comment: Ok my last guess would be to make sure you pass in the 'pause' argument into 'onBeforeAction' and if the sub isnt ready pause the action until it is ready. When it is ready then render your template. Sorry if that doesnt help I'm just throwing out suggestions and I'm on mobile so I can't type out the above code properly.

Comment: @user4043200 yeah it works but you have to do all three ways to make it work in Chrome.